# Are shops in Slovakia open on 15. August?

Tags: museums, shopping, public-holidays, slovakia

I plan a day-trip to Bratislava on 15. August. In some countries (eg. Austria) on this day all  shops are closed.

Do you happen to know, if shops are also closed in Slovakia on 15. August? What about museums and such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that Slovakia does not celebrate Mary's Assumption, unlike Austria:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Slovakia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Austria#Austria

So, it's pretty safe to say that shops and museum will be open in Slovakia on the 15th of August.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on 15 august shops in Slovakia are open, and other places like museum also are open.